# Regex PHP to extract a photo gallery from an HTML string

Tags: php, html, regex

In my HTML page I have multiple occurrences of this code:

```
<a onclick="window.open('hxxp://www.mysite.com/gallery/foto_amatoriali/foto_gallery_prova/foto_amatoriali.jpg');" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img height="90" alt="foto_amatoriali.jpg" src="hxxp://www.mysite.com/gallery/foto_amatoriali/foto_gallery_prova/th/foto_amatoriali_thumb.jpg" width="120" vspace="4" />
</a>
```

What I wanna do is with php extract all IMAGE SOURCES LINK

```
hxxp://www.mysite.com/gallery/foto_amatoriali/foto_gallery_prova/foto_amatoriali.jpg
```

Between `window.open('`  and  `');`

I created this REGEX PATTERN:

```
open\(\'([^()]*)\'
```

I tested via an online REGEX edtior and it seems to work but when I do it via php it works not correctly.

In many case it extract not only the link but LINK plus `window.open('`

Someone can help me with the correct REGEX syntax ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this with PHP? What have you tried so far with PHP?

Comment: Change your regex to `open\(\'([^']*)\'\)` and then print the index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=open\(\')([^()]*)(?=\'\))
```